# Reduce the dimensions of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

Im having trouble iterating thru this array of product information with the desired result of echoing google ecommerce tracking code for each item. How do I reduce the dimension by one. In short -

How do turn this:

```
Array (
    [array] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [product_id] => 7
            [prod_count] => 1
            [price] => 19.99
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [product_id] => 6
            [prod_count] => 3
            [price] => 19.99
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [product_id] => 5
            [prod_count] => 2
            [price] => 19.99
        )
        [3] => Array (
            [product_id] => 4
            [prod_count] => 4
            [price] => 14.99
        )
        [4] => Array (
            [product_id] => 3
            [prod_count] => 5
            [price] => 19.99
        )
    )
 )
```

into this:

```
 Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [product_id] => 7
                [prod_count] => 1
                [price] => 19.99
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [product_id] => 6
                [prod_count] => 3
                [price] => 19.99
            )
            [2] => Array (
                [product_id] => 5
                [prod_count] => 2
                [price] => 19.99
            )
            [3] => Array (
                [product_id] => 4
                [prod_count] => 4
                [price] => 14.99
            )
            [4] => Array (
                [product_id] => 3
                [prod_count] => 5
                [price] => 19.99
            )
        )
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP wizard but maybe you can encapsulate the product information (product_id, prod_count, price) into an object, and then make a collection (array) of those?  Then you'd only have one "dimension" to deal with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious answer for the example would be:

```
$array = $array['array'];
```

However, assuming there are multiple arrays as level one:

```
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$array);
```

Comment: You saved my day man. Now i can easily iterate thru them and echo google tracking code. Can I buy you a coffee?

Comment: Hah, that would be difficult, I doubt we even share a timezone.. But you're welcome nonetheless :)

Comment: saved mine too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
   "withinArray" => array(
       "withinMoreArray" => array(
           "andEvenMoreArray" => array(
           )
       )
   )
);

$arr = current($arr);
// OR
$arr = $arr['withinArray'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Let's say this is your big array:
/*Array (
    [array] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [product_id] => 7
            [prod_count] => 1
            [price] => 19.99
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [product_id] => 6
            [prod_count] => 3
            [price] => 19.99
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [product_id] => 5
            [prod_count] => 2
            [price] => 19.99
        )
        [3] => Array (
            [product_id] => 4
            [prod_count] => 4
            [price] => 14.99
        )
        [4] => Array (
            [product_id] => 3
            [prod_count] => 5
            [price] => 19.99
        )
    )
 )*/

$littlearray = $bigarray['array'];
?>
```