# algorithm complexity of reducing multidimensional array by 1

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The sample array (might differ in amount of levels or members.

```
$dataset_groups = array(
    'first_level1_group' => array(
        array(
            'fname' => 'John', 
            'lname' => 'Smith', 
            'favourite_fruit' => array('apple', 'pear'), 
        ), 
    ),
    'second_level1_group' => array(
        array(
            'fname' => 'Adam', 
            'lname' => 'Smith', 
            'favourite_fruit' => array('apple', 'pear'), 
        ),
        array(
            'fname' => 'Jane', 
            'lname' => 'Smith', 
            'favourite_fruit' => array('apple', 'pineapple'), 
        ), 
    ),
    'third_level1_group' => array(
        array(
            'fname' => 'Andrew', 
            'lname' => 'Smith', 
            'favourite_fruit' => array('apple', 'pear'), 
        ),
        array(
            'fname' => 'Ross', 
            'lname' => 'Smith', 
            'favourite_fruit' => array('apple', 'pineapple'), 
        ), 
    ),
);
```

Me wanting to make it to something similar to (get rid of `first_level1`, etc)

```
$dataset_groups = array(
    array(
        'fname' => 'John', 
        'lname' => 'Smith', 
        'favourite_fruit' => array('apple', 'pear'), 
    ), 
    array(
        'fname' => 'Adam', 
        'lname' => 'Smith', 
        'favourite_fruit' => array('apple', 'pear'), 
    ),
    array(
        'fname' => 'Jane', 
        'lname' => 'Smith', 
        'favourite_fruit' => array('apple', 'pineapple'), 
    ), 
    array(
        'fname' => 'Andrew', 
        'lname' => 'Smith', 
        'favourite_fruit' => array('apple', 'pear'), 
    ),
    array(
        'fname' => 'Ross', 
        'lname' => 'Smith', 
        'favourite_fruit' => array('apple', 'pineapple'), 
    ), 
);
```

The question is whether something like this

```
foreach ($dataset_groups as $group_key => $group) {

    if (empty($dataset)) {

        $dataset = $group;

    } else {

        $dataset = array_merge($dataset, $group);

    }

}
```

Would be more efficient (me thinking that this should be O(n) complexity) or this (as I have found in one of the suggestions)?
`$dataset = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $dataset_groups);`

Since I don't know the inner workings of `call_user_func_array()` it's hard for me to determine (though I have a feeling that it would be pretty much the same).

EDIT1: basically I'm wondering whether there would be a reason to switch to `call_user_func_array()` besides readability.

Comment: Looking at your output, `array_values()` looks sufficient. Also, for such cases, you shouldn't care about time complexity because you have to visit them to tweak them. If you add them to new array, new array will have to accommodate all of them which takes time. If you unset the key itself, that would also restructure the array and take approximately same amount of time.

Comment: @vivek_23 `array_values()` wold not work really as it would return the same structure array except instead of `['first_level1']` it would turn it into numbered index

Comment: Your current output array would also have numeric indexes if you do a print_r() on them. If that is not the case, can you share a demo on https://3v4l.org/ ?

Comment: Also, there is no advantage of calling `call_user_func_array` over just a simple `array_merge` call.  `call_user_func_array` is used when **_we_** have defined functions or methods. There is no point in calling API methods with it.

Comment: @vivek_23 Here is a demo https://3v4l.org/NpeLj

Comment: And the question where the `call_user_func_array` was suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153100/reduce-the-dimensions-of-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: Your existing code is fine although it can be simplified to `foreach ($dataset_groups as $group_key => $group) {
    $dataset = array_merge($dataset ?? array(), $group);
}`

Comment: @NulisDefo Your current arrays which have data are inside another arrays. Looking at your post, I just realized the array you shared is incorrect. Hence, array_values() is not an option.  Your shared code has the actual structure. The advantage of using call_user_func_array would just be to have a kind of 1-liner instead of manually digging down recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use array_reduce() with an anonymous function instead of a foreach loop.

```
$newArray = array_reduce($dataset_groups, 
  function($carry, $item){
    return array_merge($carry,$item);
  }, []
);
```